# Querydsl need to query where integer column is less than value

Tags: java, querydsl

I am having trouble writing a JPAQuery that will execute a simple less than or equal to comparison on an integer column.  I have QCommand generated querydsl object which I am trying to use with a JPAquery to execute this very simple query.  The query I want to execute would look like this using SQL:

```
select * from command where retry_count <= 10;
```

The generated QCommand object defines the retryCount parameter as:

```
public final SimplePath<Integer> retryCount = createSimple("retryCount", Integer.class);
```

I have noticed that because it is a SimplePath, when I try to write the JPAQuery, the retryCount variable does not have comparison operators like loe or goe.  That column/variable only allows me to do a isNull, isNotNull, eq, and other very simple operators, but no comparison operators.  This would look like below, however, obviously not execute the comparison I want, but it works without error:

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(command).where(command.retryCount.isNotNull()).list(command);
```

In looking around I saw there is a way to create a NumberPath, which seems to be what I want, however, when I attempt the below code I get an exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'retryCount'. Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it."

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
NumberPath<Integer> retryCount = new NumberPath<Integer>(Integer.class, "retryCount");
return query.from(command).where(retryCount.loe(10)).list(command);
```

So, how can I "add" this path to the source.  I have looked around and I cannot find an example that does this nor an explanation as to how this is supposed to be done.  The javadocs are not very helpful in this situation.  I had been moving along nicely with querydsl, but this is the first roadblock and I'm stumped on writing one of the most simple queries.  Any assistance or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query with manual paths works like this

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
NumberPath<Integer> retryCount = new NumberPath<Integer>(Integer.class, command, "retryCount");
return query.from(command).where(retryCount.loe(10)).list(command);
```

The difference is that you create the retryCount path as a top level path, where as it should be created as a property path with a parent.

How does the Command class look like? There might be some issues in the code generation.

Comment: This works for me!  The error is gone and the query returns values.  Thanks for your help Timo.

Comment: Ok, but could you still tell me how you got the SimplePath? That shouldn't have happened.

Comment: Hmm, I basically just use the annotation processor in eclipse to generate the QCommand and other querydsl files.  I'm using the querydsl-jpa-2.7.1-apt-hibernate-one-jar.jar and specify the output directory and the files are generated in a source file directory after every build.  Am I perhaps using a wrong version of this?  I had to try several different versions of that jar file because I was getting null pointer exceptions with other versions when it attempted to generate the files.

Comment: What is the type of retryCount in your domain class? Is it annotated?